# How to execute EXE file on Windows 2008 using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, permissions

How to execute EXE file on Windows 2008 using ASP.NET and IIS7? I have tried to run code below but it seems do not work. The code is executed without any error but I do not see Notepad in Processes list. Everything works fine if I use ASP.NET developer server but not with IIS7.

```
string enginePath = "notepad";

var password = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (char character in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Credentials"])
    password.AppendChar(character);

var p = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                    {
                        FileName = enginePath,    
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                    }
            };


p.StartInfo.UserName = "Administrator";
p.StartInfo.Password = password;

p.Start();
```

Comment: i really hope you aren't keeping the server administrator password in a web.config file.

Comment: Yes, I keep but this is just test project. I need to get exe execution working. If it will work with admin password I will go further and use another account.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/p/1117187/1734920.aspx

Comment: @sgmeyer He's checked the process list for the process - it would be there even if it was invisible. Also, he is trying to run it on the server, not the client.

Comment: @Tomas What do you get if you print out the `p.ID` value (i.e. the PID). Does this match up with anything in process explorer? Have you clicked "Show processes for all users" in Task Manager? Have you tried using Process Explorer instead of Task Manager?

Comment: p.Id prints process id when I run demo project on IIS7 but Process Explorer do not show notepad in process list.
The problem is what I do not know what tools to use to find out where is the problem? I think this is related with permission but unfortunately Windows 2008 do not give enough information about security issues. I have checked event viewer and what I see is "Application popup: notepad.exe - Application Error : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application. "

Answer (score 1):

In response to security concerns Microsoft has continually increased the isolation of the IIS process such that you can not (or I have not found a work around which will allow you to...) invoke anything outside the IIS application domain directly. You can build a Windows service which can use WCF channels to cross that boundary indirectly. That service (configured to be allowed to interact with the desktop) can in turn launch your Notepad.exe.

It is a bit of a kludge to make it happen and I will certainly be interested to see if someone else has a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed lines below and it suddenly started working. I can't explain how it is possible to run exe under IIS7 account but it is working.

```
p.StartInfo.UserName = "Administrator";
p.StartInfo.Password = password;
```